# $this->db->query() returning nothing CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to execute following query using codeigniter , but its giving nothing/null as return value,

**Code with query:**

```
public function getNumbersByComplainId($cid){
        $qur = $this->db->query("
            SET @sk := (SELECT app_users.skeeper_phone as sphone FROM app_users WHERE app_users. app_user_type = 'SKEEPER' LIMIT 1);
            SELECT 
            acs.id as complainId,
            IF(
                (@sk) > 0,
                @sk,
                ''
            ) as sk_phone,
            (
                SELECT 
                IF(
                    auu.institute_phone IS NULL,
                    auu.department_phone,
                    auu.institute_phone
                ) as cphone
                FROM app_users as auu
                WHERE auu.id = acs.app_customer_id
                LIMIT 1
            ) as cphone,
            (
                SELECT auuu.other_user_phone as ephone
                FROM app_users as auuu,app_admin_assign_eng as aase
                WHERE aase.app_complain_service_id = acs.id AND auuu.id = aase.engineer_id
                LIMIT 1
            ) as ephone,
            (
                SELECT auuu.fullname as ename
                FROM app_users as auuu,app_admin_assign_eng as aase
                WHERE aase.app_complain_service_id = acs.id AND auuu.id = aase.engineer_id
                LIMIT 1
            ) as ename,
            (
                SELECT auuu.other_user_phone as ephone
                FROM app_users as auuu,app_admin_assign_eng as aase
                WHERE aase.app_complain_service_id = acs.id AND auuu.id = aase.admin_id
                LIMIT 1
            ) as aphone
            FROM app_complain_services as acs,app_users as au
            WHERE 
            acs.id = '".$cid."'
            GROUP BY acs.id
            ");

        print_r($qur);
        //print_r($this->db->last_query());

        if($qur && $qur->num_rows() > 0){
            return $qur->result();
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

function is returning `null` , and `$qur` variable is `null` probably

**Personal Attempt:**

- checked using `print_r($this->db->last_query())` , returning valid sql query which i run on phpmyadmin works fine.

Comment: ?????????? anyone

Comment: try if($qur && ($qur->num_rows() > 0))

Comment: "and $qur variable is `null` probably" Is it `null` or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try these condition it working

```
 if ($quer->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($quer->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
```

This may help you